# Get First Attached Image as Thumbnail in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

So, by default, wordpress thumbnail function gets only the Uploaded Image as Thumbnail.
But, what I need is a code which can get the First Image, whether attached (from another website) or uploaded, as thumbnail and show on home page,.

Anyone know how to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [WordPress › Get the Image « WordPress Plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/get-the-image/) to grab the first image, first attached image or a default image.